# How to write a rewriterule for images that dose not exist in Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder in my site root **www.mysite.com/Folder1** and want to write a rewriterule witch I can place it in .htaccess file with below conditions:

1. If an image (.jpg, .jpeg, .gif and .png file) dose not exists in
   **www.mysite.com/Folder1**, the image certainly is in **www.mysite.com/Folder2** and Apache should rewrite it to new URL.
2. If an image (.jpg, .jpeg, .gif and .png file) already exists do nothing.

For example when the url `www.mysite.com/Folder1/ImageDoseNotExist.jpg` (witch ImageDoseNotExist.jpg dose not exist in Folder1) is called, Apache loads `www.mysite.com/Folder2/ImageDoseNotExist.jpg`. Its obviously that if ImageDoseNotExist.jpg exists in Folder1 Apache must load it and do nothing!

Thanks if help me.

Comment: Im not a htaccess crack but i think this is not possible with pure htaccess redirect to a .php file and let it do the fileswitching

Comment: I think it's possible. Like this  `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/images/$0 -s
RewriteRule ^img.*\.jpg$ var/images/$0
`